# Retreiving data using a sql query for a specific scenario

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am having a resultset/table which is as below

`user_id |date_time         |name  |
---------|------------------|------|
1        |05/04/2017 08:00  |Jack  |
2        |05/04/2017 09:00  |Adams |
1        |05/04/2017 13:06  |Jack  |
1        |05/04/2017 13:45  |Jack  |
1        |06/04/2017 09:15  |Jack  |
1        |07/04/2017 10:00  |Jack  |
1        |10/04/2017 12:00  |Jack  |
2        |10/04/2017 12:30  |Adams |
1        |10/04/2017 15:44  |Jack  |`

I want to sort the `date_time` in ascending order for each user for each day. 
I am expecting the result to be as below: (I am having problem with the second row and the last but one). All rows for `Jack` on `April 5` should be together, followed by `Adams`; whether the `date_time` of `Adams` is in between the `date_time` of `Jack` for that day

`user_id |date_time         |name  |
---------|------------------|------|
1        |05/04/2017 08:00  |Jack  |
1        |05/04/2017 13:06  |Jack  |
1        |05/04/2017 13:45  |Jack  |
2        |05/04/2017 09:00  |Adams |
1        |06/04/2017 09:15  |Jack  |
1        |07/04/2017 10:00  |Jack  |
1        |10/04/2017 12:00  |Jack  |
1        |10/04/2017 15:44  |Jack  |
2        |10/04/2017 12:30  |Adams |`

---

Adding the query I had used to arrive at this resultset:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_table.user_id
    ,diary_table.date_time
    ,user_table.NAME
FROM user_table
INNER JOIN diary_table ON user_table.user_id = diary_table.diary_user_id
    AND (
        date_time >= '06-Apr-2017 00:00:00'
        AND date_time <= '15-Apr-2017 23:59:59'
        )
    AND diar_user_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT diar_user_id
        FROM diary_table
        INNER JOIN event_table ON event_table.event_id = diary_table.diar_event_id
        WHERE event_table.event_name = 'Lunch'
            AND (
                date_time >= '06-Apr-2017 00:00:00'
                AND date_time <= '15-Apr-2017 23:59:59'
                )
        )
ORDER BY date_time ASC
    ,NAME
    ,ASC
```

Comment: What you tried so far? include that as well

Comment: Well, this is a result of a sql query and I am stuck with this resultset.

Comment: Can you post us query you using?

Comment: Added the query now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this solved by using a day column. Here goes the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, date_time), 0) AS theDay
    ,user_table.user_id
    ,diary_table.date_time
    ,user_table.NAME
FROM user_table
INNER JOIN diary_table ON user_table.user_id = diary_table.diary_user_id
    AND (
        date_time >= '06-Apr-2017 00:00:00'
        AND date_time <= '15-Apr-2017 23:59:59'
        )
    AND diar_user_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT diar_user_id
        FROM diary_table
        INNER JOIN event_table ON event_table.event_id = diary_table.diar_event_id
        WHERE event_table.event_name = 'Lunch'
            AND (
                date_time >= '06-Apr-2017 00:00:00'
                AND date_time <= '15-Apr-2017 23:59:59'
                )
        )
ORDER BY theDay
    ,NAME ASC
    ,date_time ASC
```